# How do I add every column in a pandas dataframe to a list except for the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Normally, I would be able to call dataframe.columns for a list of all columns, but I don't want to include the very first column in my list. Writing each column manually is an option, but one I'd like to avoid, given the few hundred column headers I'm working with. I do need to use this column, though, so deleting it from the dataframe entirely wouldn't work. How can I put every column into a list except for the first one?

Comment: `dataframe.columns[1:]` or `list(dataframe.columns[1:])`?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
list(df.columns[1:])
```